# How do you switch backing bean objects in JSF?

Tags: ajax, jsf, myfaces

Suppose I several tags, text input, radios, etc referencing one instance object.  I would like to use a dropdown on that page to switch the references mentioned before to another instance of the object.

This part is pretty easy with change listener.  However, the problem I have is the values currently displayed on the screen are getting set into the new, second instance.

I would like the current values to be stored in the current instance, and then the when the page refreshes I would like the new values to come from the new instance and be displayed on the screen.

Is there was way to do this?  Does my question make any sense?

Grae

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? Why did you tagged `[ajax]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value change listener is exactly the wrong tool for this, because it gets called before the values are set.

What you want is an action listener, which will get call after the values from the page are validated and set.

Comment: I know actionListeners get called before actions, and now I know changeListeners get called before actionListeners.  Is there a complete list of of the order somewhere?